# SP 2010 The maximum number of Web Parts for all zones on this page has been exceeded

Tags: web-part, error, custom-web-part-property

I am developing SharePoint web parts and as soon as I click on the left navigation to add a web part to the page I get the below error.

I am using SP 2010 VS 2010

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The maximum number of Web Parts for all zones on this page has been exceeded. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.MaxZonePartsExceededException: The maximum number of Web Parts for all zones on this page has been exceeded.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[MaxZonePartsExceededException: The maximum number of Web Parts for all zones on this page has been exceeded.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CreateWebPartsFromRowSetData(Boolean onlyInitializeClosedWebParts) +10047
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.LoadWebParts() +146
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.OnPageInitComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +288
   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnInitComplete(EventArgs e) +11045694
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiEditPage.OnInitComplete(EventArgs e) +225
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1674
```

Comment: Er.. you have too many web parts on the page? Try [deleting some other web parts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg153557.aspx).

Comment: This problem can occur when a user has created too many views for a list.
I have a user that has done this and I, too, am looking for resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Try opening your page in web part management mode by adding

```
?contents=1
```

to the end of your url

If your webpart page URL is

```
http://myportal/pages/default.aspx
```

Browse to

```
 http://myportal/pages/default.aspx?contents=1
```

This will list all webparts, and allow you to delete some of them.

By the way, how many webparts do you have per zone and in total?

Comment: i am not sure i understand

Comment: I edited the answer. Hope it's clearer now :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can simply change this line in web.config file on your frontend

```
<WebPartLimits MaxZoneParts="50" PropertySize="1048576" />
```

also this change can be propaganated to all WFEs through Feature, using `SPWebConfigModification` class and FeatureEventReciever

Answer (score 0):

If you close a web part it does not get removed from the page - it just gets hidden. Because of this, you can have a page with many web parts on it, even though there appears to be none at runtime. To remove a web part from a page it must be deleted.

I expect that this is the reason you are getting the error. Using the techniques Jorge mentioned, you will be able to see all the web parts on the page and delete those that you no longer need.