# How many List Views can be created

Tags: list, list-view

I have a Site that has 88 Sub-Sites. I have an Announcements board at the top level site with selections that then can be filtered down to the Sub-Sites. I am using a Webpart and changing the view on the Webpart based on what site I am on.

How many list Views can I create on a List?

I have seen some that say 50, some that 5,000 etc. Not really sure what the correct answer is. Been looking for two days is this documented somewhere, or does someone have some experience with this?

Answer (score 3):

The issue really isn't the number of views you can create, it is the fact that only so many will be available in the dropdown for selecting those views.  You can create as many as you like but  only 50 (possibly less) will be displayed in the drop down for selection.

Comment: Can you provide any documentation or anything to support your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The official Software Boundaries and limit from Microsoft - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx

As you can see the limit of Views per List is not specified.

But from this discussion (SharePoint 2007) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293299/moss-2007-maximum-number-of-views-for-one-list Its mentioned as 50 views per list. We can't be sure until we try it.

Comment: See that's my question. I saw that in the SharePoint 2007 it was suggested that you could do 50 views, but never confirmed. Has someone gone over the 50 view threshold?

Comment: @IkeRebout You can test this by adding more view. For example add views (100 view) using PowerShell. This will give you the answer.

Comment: Do not have access to power shell on the system (restricted) found solution before.

Answer (score 1):

issue is how many views displayed in the dropdown, if you just want to use UI then in the drop down you will get 1st 50 views. Even you can create more than 50 views.

But i think with development /programming, you can access the more than 50 views( calling by view name).

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice Found:

1. Create the list
2. Open up Sharepoint Designer 2010
3. Open List and select view (on the right hand side)
4. Select the list in Design view (you will notice if you are in split view that the code will be highlighted in blue
5. Select Webpart ribbon
6. Select "To Site Gallery"
7. Title it and load it.
8. Go back to website and add the webpart that you just placed to the Site Gallery
9. Edit the Webpart

10 Right under Selected View it says "edit the current view" click there.

11.Edit the view as this is the same process as if you created a view but it is page specific (meaning it does not save back to the original list keeping the views under the 50 maximum)

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to tackle the issue, if your using webparts is to just filter from within the webpart, then you would not need to create more than 50 views.

Answer (score 0):

There is not list view count limit 50 pcs in SharePoint (I've tested it on SharePoint 2013). It is true only for personal views, if there will be more than 50 personal views, error message will be thrown, when user will try to open one of his/her personal views:

```
The maximum number of web parts for all zones on this page has been exceeded
```

As is written [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21148/sp-2010-the-maximum-number-of-web-parts-for-all-zones-on-this-page-has-been-exce), this limit can be extended by modifying Web.config:

```
<WebPartLimits MaxZoneParts="50" PropertySize="1048576" />
```

Answer (score 0):

And to give this really old post another perspective, I just saved a list as template from a SharePoint 2016 onPrem. Afterwards, I tried to apply that .stp file on another server.

This ended with a

> Sorry, something went wrong

exception.

After searching through the ULS Log, to find the cause for that I encountered this entry:

```
The number of views have reached the maximum supported (90). View processing will stop for list
```

Even if this is not a documented maximum, it seems to disable the Save as template and apply function, if your list has more then 90 views.