# Filter View for Multiple Users

Tags: view

We have a large spreadsheet that is shared with about 50 individuals each day. Different users are looking at different items and updating specific status events.

When we were working in Google Sheets, there was a 'filter view' functionality that would allow individual users to set up their own view that would not be impacted by other users moving around on the sheet. Does Sharepoint have anything similar?

Comment: What version of SharePoint you are using? SharePoint online/2019/2016/2013?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all your requirements.

But if you want to create a view and filter the data depend on the current logged in user then you can use `[Me]` in filter.

Or If you want to create a view in list which will be visible to only you then you can create a personal view on SharePoint list. (You can check for maximum number of personal views can be created per SharePoint list).

**References**:

1. [Filter views based on current logged in user](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4).
2. [Create personal view in SharePoint list](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9).
3. [Limitations on number of views per list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129250/how-many-list-views-can-be-created).

Comment: Does this answers your question or it helped you in any way to get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking but your users should be able to edit the view of the list, filter columns and such and once they have that setup how they like it they can click on the following to save the view.

[image: Save SharePoint List View]

They should then be prompted for a view name and if the view should be made public or not. Once saved they can access the view from the drop down above by selecting it.

Thanks,
Zach